# gatsbyjs (SSR) new data rendreing in server

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering

i have created a gatsby js ecommerce website with what is called in documentation ( SSR ) using gatsby-node.js and gatsby-ssr.js files.

i noticed that it's much like a prerendering then a server side rendering !

what happen if new data is created in the database, will gatsby actualy server side the new data and generate the code in the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If new source data is created then you need to trigger a new build. If you're using netlify this is pretty easy to accomplish by using a build hook. (a unique url that triggers a build) Or you could even set it to build on a timer.

The reason it's set up like this is because it's a static site generator. There is no server running.

If you want to load data in real time you can always do that too.. but it won't be server side rendered.